# How to store data when offline with a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, nosql, offlineapps

I am currently creating a React Native app which will require the user to be able to store data offline and then once only it will sync to the database. I have heard of PouchDB but don't quite understand how to implement it so advice on this might be a solution.

I am unsure which services to use due this being my first time creating a complete React Native app. I have experience using React JS, Express and Sequelize however I don't think I can use Sequelize with a React Native App.

I would like to use either NoSql or a MySQL database, however, I am open to either.

Any advice on what services to yous, languages, guides, videos would be great as I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947756/does-react-native-support-indexed-db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cloud Firestore which is part of Firebase. It's a NoSQL, offline-first database that works as you are describing and it's pretty easy to use with React Native.

Docs: https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Comment: Hi Ewan, thanks for your answer! Just to confirm , so my app will require users to enter data and sometimes they may be in a location with no wifi. Does Firestore save the data on the device locally?

Comment: No problem man. Yes, it uses an offline cached version of the database to allow you to read, write etc and then syncs everything up once the connection is restored. More details on this feature here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Answer (score 2):

You can use redux-persist. It allows you to store data in key value pair. It is what i am using for storing data offline and syncing to db when required.
It is handly while using react-redux. You can Blacklist or Whitelist reducers to persist data from only specific reducers.

Here is few links which will be useful

1. [NPM link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)
2. [More on redux persist](https://itnext.io/react-native-why-you-should-be-using-redux-persist-8ad1d68fa48b)
3. [Setting up](https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/the-definitive-guide-to-redux-persist-84738167975)

Comment: This is correct, you can combine redux and redux-persist to easily persist offline data. Personally I tried to combine this with a Django backend to create an offline first database and found it fairly difficult which is why I opted to use Firebase instead as a pre-made solution, but if you don't need the online database and just want to store data locally on the device, this would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this question was asked a year ago but I found this question as I was researching an offline database solution for my own app.

One response here recommends **Firebase** which fits the criteria of your question perfectly but I would **use it with caution**. Firebase is really great for online storage and has an offline storage feature, but is not meant as a long-term offline storage solution. I've only added this caution since you said you said "once only it will sync to the database" See a couple of resources I've found on Firebase:

- [Used as an offline-only solution, Firebase gets slower over time since it uses a cache rather than actual storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871927/using-firebase-firestore-in-offline-only-mode)
- [Official documentation on Firebase offline cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

The offline database solution that I'll be using is [MMKV, an offline storage library developed by WeChat](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv). I found it while looking through this [list of offline storage solutions](https://reactnative.directory/?search=storage) while looking at [AsyncStorage (Now Depreciated)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage).

Hopefully, this response will help others like me decide what storage solution to use as well! **Edit: This library doesn't work with expo.**